# Designing a support ticket workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I know this is a really basic question, but I need to build a workflow where users can create support request tickets (stored in a list) that are assigned to one member of "support group". I've got the list, I've got the group created and it has some members. Once a user creates the ticket, it needs to be assigned to a member that does not already have a ticket/task assigned to them.

I was thinking of creating a separate list to keep track of what members have tasks assigned to them but it seems to me that this should be something that SharePoint Designer can just do OOB. However after a bit of searching I've found nothing specific. Can anyone help? I'll be glad to provide any more information needed.

Any help or insight is much appreciated.

Comment: Edit: I found out the requirements were to use workflows in SharePoint designer only. I was able to accomplish this by having a separate list to track which ticket was assigned to which engineer and then manipulating that list in Workflow, assigning tasks based on the content of that list. Not ideal, but it met the requirements of the exercise. I'd like to mark this complete but unfortunately could not use the answer provided by jpussacq

Answer (score 0):

I think it's very difficult to be able to resolve this requirement with SharePoint Designer. I would recommend you use an event receiver. This requires programming in Visual Studio with C #.

An event receiver is something like a database trigger. It will let you perform an action after the ticket has been created. At that point you can determine which person to assign the task and make that assignment.

I hope you helps.

Comment: Thank you. I'm pretty comfortable with coding in VS but I think the requirements are to do this in Designer only. However we were covering event receivers at the same time (this is for a class) so that should be allowed. I'm guessing you can check if a user has a task assigned to them programmatically? I'll have to look into that.

Comment: Do not think you have inconvenient. SharePoint uses CAML as query language on the lists. It is much more limited than SQL, but I think you will reach to view the free person to attend a ticket. The other point to consider is that there are synchronous and asynchronous events. The seconds run after the item has been created. I think you need to update a field of the item (designated person). Si I think the asynchronous be a better option. Greetings!